# Issue on log4js File Appender

Tags: javascript, logging, log4js-node

I am using Log4js Library to print the log message in a file. In that I am getting 2 issues. Such as:

1. `12:00:40 PM ERROR Log4js - TypeError: netscape.security.PrivilegeManager is undefined`
          in Non-IE Browser. Please tell me how to fix this exception. While Using IE , It's
          working fine.
2. How to get the `CATALINA_HOME` in the JavaScript part. I am using Tomcat.
          To get this `CATALINA_HOME` in Log4j, we need to write as follow
          `log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.base}/logs/MyLogs.log`.
          If I'll write the catalina.base, not working in the JavaScript.

Here is my code please have a look on my code and detect the error causing line to have the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(name) {
        var date = new Date();
        var log = Log4js.getLogger("fileAppender");
        log.setLevel(Log4js.Level.ALL);
        var toAppend=date.getFullYear()+"-"+(date.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date.getDate();
        var fileAppender = new Log4js.FileAppender("${catalina.base}\\logs\\JSLogging."+toAppend+".log");
        log.addAppender(fileAppender);
        log.debug("My Debugging");
        log.info("My Information");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: To get CATALINA_HOME? Correct me if i am wrong. is it system environment variable?

Comment: Ya , You are absolutely right.For that ,I have set the CATALINA_HOME in my CLASSPATH. Still unable to get in Java Script File.
VinayakPingale

Comment: You cant get env variable like that. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770446/javascript-environment-variables

Comment: My Question is , How can I get that value in my HTML Page using JavaScript ? VinayakPingale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding    `<script type="text/javascript" src="log4javascript.js"></script>`    in the code seems it is not able to get the reference of the main script.
see if this can help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create the logger
    var log = log4javascript.getLogger();

    // Create a PopUpAppender with default options
    var popUpAppender = new log4javascript.PopUpAppender();

    // Change the desired configuration options
    popUpAppender.setFocusPopUp(true);
    popUpAppender.setNewestMessageAtTop(true);

    // Add the appender to the logger
    log.addAppender(popUpAppender);

    // Test the logger
    log.debug("Hello world!");
</script>
```

`enter code here`

use this [link](http://log4javascript.org/docs/quickstart.html)

Comment: I don't think so that It is not getting the reference from main source.Because, It is working and saving all the log message in the Location Specified when I am using IE but, not working for Non-IE Browser.

It is a popUp Appender . But, As per my requirement I need a FileAppender where all of my log message is going  to Store.