# Pass variable to Selenium-IDE script

Tags: msbuild, selenium, selenium-ide

Is it possible for an MSBuild script to pass an argument to the Selenium test runner that can then be used by a Selenium-IDE test script? I was hoping I could do something like...

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox $(SeleniumTestBaseUrl) myTestSuite.html -myVariable $(environmentSpecificVar)
```

...and then use it from within my Selenium-IDE script like...

```
waitForTextPresent    The passed in variable is ${myVariable}
```

Theres no problem passing in an environment specific url (thats what the SeleniumTestBaseUrl is) but I'm having trouble passing anything else environment specific into my Selenium-IDE scripts.

Thanks!

Comment: I've adopted the exceptionally nasty policiy of XmlPoke'ing the appropriate variable into the script, as nothing else seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

The following command will allow you to retrieve some environment variables from within Selenium IDE.  This also works in Selenium RC if you are using *firefox as your browser.

```
Command: storeEval
Target: Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/environment;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIEnvironment).get('USERNAME');
Value: username
```

Reference: [Finding the currently logged in user from a Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399263/finding-the-currently-logged-in-user-from-a-firefox-extension)

Answer (score 2):

The key is the Selenium Parameter -userExtensions

First, let the script create a temporary js-file (in this case getting a Jenkins parameter):

```
echo "var myvariable='$myJenkinsVariable'" > user-extensions.js
```

Then passing the user variable to Selenium like in this example:

```
java -jar /var/lib/selenium/selenium.jar -htmlSuite *firefox http://flowcom.se "build/suite.html" "build/report/report.html" -userExtensions "user-extensions.js"
```

In my testfile it is then possible to get the variable via storeEval:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>myvariable</td>
    <td>myvariable</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${myvariable}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it as environment variable:

```
 set myVariable=$(environmentSpecificVar) && java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite *firefox $(SeleniumTestBaseUrl) myTestSuite.html
```

See detailes [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html).

Comment: Setting the environment variable seems to work but I am unable to use it in my script - I've not found a selenium command to capture an environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running a java command, you should try setting a specific property at the command line using the -D flag:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar ... -DpropertyFoo=valueBar
```

To call that in MSBuild, you would simply set a property and wrap the above command in an Exec task:

```
<Exec command="java -jar selenium-server.jar ... -DpropertyFoo=$(propertyFoo)" />
```

I'm not too familiar with Selenium IDE scripts so I don't know if you'll be able to access properties that way, but this is what I do when invoking ant tasks from my MSBuild scripts.

Comment: Thanks, setting the environment var works but doesn't seem to be accesible via Selenium.