# How to get the windows (logged in) username in Firefox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I am working on a very old web application(only for intranet usage). In the code, the developer is obtaining the logged in account via this

`var wshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
document.getElementById('userId').value = wshNetwork.UserName;`

This works only in IE. How can I get the logged in account in Firefox/chrome?

I have looked in to other thread (ex: [Finding the currently logged in user from a Firefox extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399263/finding-the-currently-logged-in-user-from-a-firefox-extension)) but that's only for extension.

Are there any other ways to get the domain logged in username in Firefox/Chrome?

Comment: Can you do some server-side coding as well; or is this limited to client (html, javascript) ?

Comment: server side is possible I presume but that means lots of code change has to happen. Since this a legacy application, it is tough to modify  :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is severely security-sensitive information - the main attack vector for compromising your computer. In IE it also only works for trusted websites such as localhost, or with special configuration for the local network - never on internet without additional configuration. Sandboxed JS will never be able to access this information - extensions are considered elevated.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that I would do on server side. Providing you're using IIS, I would set the page to be using only Windows Authentication, read the current user on server side, and send it back to client via hidden field or javascript variable.

Comment: These are JSP based running on Webshpere

Comment: Sorry - I'm no expert in JSP, but according to google, it is possible even there - you can set sso-kerberos authentication, and read user like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167646/get-windows-username-using-java-or-jsp . This approach is browser-independent (read: supported by all major browsers).